# Remove lines corresponding to first 7 matches of a string (in a pattern range)

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I need to remove the lines corresponding to first 7 occurrences of a string from a txt file in a pattern range (string1-string2).

Example of txt file content:

```
whatever
xpto string1 foo2
whatever1 
string2
xpto1 another_foo
xpto string2

string2 foo1

whatever
string2 another_xpto
string2 string2
foo xpto string2 whatever 
anything else foo string2
xpto
string2
foo whatever
```

I need a solution with sed ranges, something like that:

```
sed '/string1/,/string2/d' file.txt
```

The point is that I don't know how to extend `/string2/` until the line corresponding to seventh match of string2. The desirable output should be:

```
whatever
anything else foo string2
xpto
string2
foo whatever
```

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern to understand why this matters and then change the word "pattern" to either "string" or "regexp" everywhere it occurs in your question so we can best answer it. Note that `/string/` makes no sense since `/` is the regexp delimiter, not the string delimiter `"` - you either meant `/regexp/` or `index($0,"string")` (the latter being if you use awk since  sed doesn't have any support for string matching).

Comment: If any of the answers you got helped you then see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next.

Answer (score 5):

```
sed -e:t -e'/string1/!b' -e'/\(.*string2\)\{7\}/d;N;bt'
```

Comment: welcome back mikeserv

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '/string1/{c=7}; c<1; {c-=gsub(/string2/, "&")}' file
```

`c` is initially 0, and set to 7 if `string1` is found. The line is printed whenever `c<1`.

The `gsub` function returns the number of times `string2` appears on each line. The counter `c` is decremented by that value.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do what you want using literal strings:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { lgth = length(end) }
index($0,beg) { inBlock = 1 }
inBlock {
    rec = $0
    while ( pos = index(rec,end) ) {
        if ( ++cnt >= min ) {
            inBlock = 0
        }
        rec = substr(rec,pos+lgth)
    }
    next
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -v beg='string1' -v end='string2' -v min=7 -f tst.awk file
whatever
anything else foo string2
xpto
string2
foo whatever
```

The above will interpret backslashes in the strings (e.g. `\t` would become a tab), if that's an issue let me know as it's an easy workaround, e.g. using `ENVIRON[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Perl

```
perl -ne '
  if (my $e = /string1/ ... s/string2/$&/g >= 7) {
      $_ .= $e =~ /E0/ ? next : <>, redo;
  }
  print;
' file
```

---

Posix sed:

```
sed -ne '
  /string1/!{p;d;}
  :loop
    n
    /string2/H
    g;s//&/7;t
  b loop
' file
```

---

**Output:**

```
whatever
anything else foo string2
xpto
string2
foo whatever
```